# Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that $f_1:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1(x)=\sup\{f(x), 0\}$, is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.
Show that $f_1:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1(x)=\sup\{f(x), 0\}$, $x\in [a,b]$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Please give me the idea how to proceed. I have no idea to solve. Please help.
Don't know what is the meaning of $\sup\{f(x),0\}$?

Comment: The $\sup$ refers to the supremum, or least upper bound. On a finite set, this just means the maximum. So, it returns $f(x)$ when $f(x) \ge 0$, and $0$ when $f(x) \le 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the last line. I understand. But how to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any real numbers $s,t$, we have
$$\sup\{s,t\}=\frac{1}{2}(s+t)+\frac{1}{2}|s-t|.$$
Thus
$$\sup\{f(x),0\}=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}|f(x)|.$$
Then the integrability of $\sup\{f(x),0\}$ follows from the integrability of $|f(x)|$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: You're welcome!